# Creating a python GUI calculator but the squareroot function is giving me problems

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

When I use the square root function immediately upon running the program it works fine. The issue is if for Example I add 8 + 8 then use the squareroot function on the output (16). I then get the error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\bigfe\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Users/bigfe/.spyder-py3/APython/net/Calc.py", line 124, in squareroot
        textbox.insert(0, math.sqrt(f_num))
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

Ive tried everything and even confirmed that the output of the addition function is a float, but it still gives me the error.

Here is my code

```
    textbox = Entry(calc, font = ('arial',20, 'bold'), bd = 30, width = 27, bg = 'gray', justify=RIGHT)
    textbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, pady=1 )
    #This is what is shown in the entry box
    textbox.insert(0, 0)

    def numEnter(num):
        if(textbox.get() == '0'): 
            textbox.delete(0, END)
        current = textbox.get()
        textbox.delete(0, END)
        ak = textbox.insert(0, str(current) + str(num))


    def clear():
        textbox.delete(0, END)
        textbox.insert(0, 0)

    def allClear():
        textbox.delete(0, END)
        textbox.insert(0, 0)
        current = 0

    def add():
        firstnum = textbox.get()
        global f_num
        global math
        f_num = float(firstnum)
        math = 'addition'
        textbox.delete(0, END)

    def subtract():
        firstnum = textbox.get()
        global f_num
        global math
        f_num = float(firstnum)
        math = 'subtraction'
        textbox.delete(0, END)

    def multiply():
        firstnum = textbox.get()
        global f_num
        global math
        f_num = float(firstnum)
        math = 'multiplication'
        textbox.delete(0, END)

    def divide():
        firstnum = textbox.get()
        global f_num
        global math
        f_num = float(firstnum)
        math = 'division'
        textbox.delete(0, END)

    def squareroot():
        firstnum = textbox.get()
        global f_num
        global math

        f_num = float(firstnum)
        textbox.delete(0, END)
        textbox.insert(0, math.sqrt(f_num))

    def pi():
        if(textbox.get() == 0): 
            textbox.delete(0, END)
        textbox.insert(0, float(math.pi))
        global frst
        frst = textbox.get()



    def equal():
        if (math == 'addition'):
            second_num = textbox.get()
            textbox.delete(0, END)
            global ans
            ans = (f_num + float(second_num))
            print(type(ans))
            textbox.insert(0, ans)

        elif (math == 'subtraction'):
            second_num = textbox.get()
            textbox.delete(0, END)
            textbox.insert(0, f_num - float(second_num))

        elif (math == 'multiplication'):
            second_num = textbox.get()
            textbox.delete(0, END)
            textbox.insert(0, f_num * float(second_num))

        elif (math == 'division'):
            second_num = textbox.get()
            textbox.delete(0, END)
            textbox.insert(0, f_num / float(second_num))
```

I left out the code for the construction of the calculator as I assumed it was not necessary. If you would like to see any other part of the code please let me know.

Comment: You use variable `math`. You should rename it as variables shouldn't have names of modules (or standard library function).

Comment: "Ive tried everything and even confirmed that the output of the addition function is a float" What things are included in "everything"? Now, read the error message again. What kind of problem does it say is in the code? `AttributeError` - so something is wrong with an attribute of something. It says that something `has no attribute sqrt` - so the problem has to be with the thing that you're trying to get the `sqrt` attribute of. Now, what does the line of code say, that has to do with `sqrt`? It says `math.sqrt(`... so the problem has to be with `math`. Now, double-check your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, names can only name one thing at a time. In particular, your global variables (names) can only name one thing at a time.

Because your code says `math.sqrt` and you expect that to get you a square-root function, I assume that you did `import math` somewhere above the code shown. When you import a module, this is an **assignment** - after Python does the work to load a module, it creates a module *object*, and `math` becomes a name for that module.

There is no special handling for modules in that regard - the name `math` is *just a name*, that can subsequently be used to name anything else - but *only one thing at a time*.

So later, when you do things like

```
    global math
    math = 'addition'
```

This makes `math` **stop** being a name for the standard library module, and start being a name for that string, instead.

Strings don't have a `sqrt` method. Methods are a kind of *attribute* - in general, `x.y` means the attribute named y, of the object (thing) named x. You get an `AttributeError` when there is an error caused by something not having an attribute with the specified name.

Use a different name to keep track of which operation you're performing.

Comment: For more information, please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the 'math' variable that you are using to any other think you like it is overlapping with you math function that you are importing